# NPM run build error in Next.js 13 (App Router)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, next.js

In my code there is an issue with the AWS access key ID  in build process of Next.js 13. However, it's important to note that the build process shouldn't require direct AWS connections or MongoDB URLs with credentials.

How to fix this error and this is my next.config.js

/** @type {import(‘next’).NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true
};